# How to get a link to PowerPoint file as slideshow in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, modern-experience, powerpoint

I have PowerPoint file uploaded in a SharePoint Online document library. I need a link that will directly open an Slideshow of the file.

How can I get a link for slideshow?

What I tried Already?

1. I tried to assign read only permission and then shared the file but still it didn't worked
2. I directly uploaded *.ppsx file to the document library and shared the link but that also opened the PowerPoint file in edit mode.

Any reference link or solution is most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the `&action=embedview` query string parameter instead of `&action=edit` in the file URL.

So your file URL should be like:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/<siteName>/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BC021A4AD-66A0-4505-A5CA-9984B810FE67%7D&action=embedview
```

Comment: Also, a blog for your reference: https://fyano.wordpress.com/2018/06/13/launch-powerpoint-files-into-slideshow-in-office-365/